# Html / PHP view controller : how to refresh just a part of a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have got a file controller.php which manages the loading of the different opages of my website.

For example, the main page is loaded thanks to the index() function of ths controller thanks to a function like this:

```
public function index() {
    $results = array();
    // Some SQL stuffs here to fill the array here…
    $this->registry->template->results = $results;
    $this->registry->template->show(‘indexView'); // load the web page
}
```

In my indexView.php file, I have got something like:

```
<div class="row">
<?php foreach ($results as $domain) {
    echo "<h3>".$domain[ "price"]. "</h3> ;
} ?></div>
```

I want to refresh the div on the onsubmit of a form alos located in the indexView.php file:

```
<form method='POST' onsubmit='javascript:goSearch();return false;'>
```

I basically need to launch most of the code of the index() function of my controller to update my array of results and to update not the whole page but just the div. How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: You should use ajax request.

Comment: You should use [**AJAX**][1].


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Are you using any JS framework?

Comment: I use   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: In that case, use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to request the data and update the page appropriately...